# Debugging a C# GUI

Tags: c#, debugging, multiprocessing, visual-studio-debugging

**Overview:**
I am debugging a C# GUI that takes in an XML file and starts a new Process to perform statistical calculations on the XML file. The process for some reason is exiting in the middle of execution with no apparent errors. A windows message box appears and says        " has stopped worked, Windows is searching for a solution"

**What I've tried:**

- I tried writing to a log to trace the
  execution of the application so I can
  see where it fails, but the process
  seems to exit at different points in
  the program.
- I tried using Visual    studios
  debugger to follow the    program
  execution, but similarly the
  process exits at different times.

**What I'd like to know:**

- Are there any other free debuggers I
  could try?
- Are there any calls I can make to see
  the current state of the process
  while it's running?
- Can anyone think of anything else to try?

any help would be great. 
Thanks.

Comment: So... you are getting many different exceptions?

Comment: Turns out I am getting an exception, but it didn't show itself, until I pretty much put the entire program in a try-catch block. It is a divide by zero exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio's debugger is the best debugging tool ever written, you should focus more on learning to use it than looking for anything else.

To answer your question, go to `Debug>Exceptions` (CTRL+D CTRL+E) and tick the `Thrown` box next to `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`. This will cause the debugger to break whenever an exception is being thrown, regardless if you quietly swallow it or completely ignore it. This should help pinpoint your problem.

Comment: +1! A bit fanboyish, but gosh darnit it's true - VS is sooooo good. :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will make that change then run through the debugger again.

Comment: @Gleno, I think my assessment is pretty objective, it's hard to find another debugger with such a rich complement of visualizers, Intellitrace (that's just insane), per-thread debugging etc.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some

```
Debugger.Break();
```

statements at strategic points in your code to force you into the debugger can be a useful way to troubleshoot stuff like this...

Just don't forget to take them out!

Answer (score 1):

You could register for the [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx) [`UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event to see if catches your problem.

Adding something like this in your Program.cs file before the main form is shown:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionEventOccured);

private static void UnhandledExceptionEventOccured(
    object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    if(ex != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to run your application through [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)